# Diagonalising an infinite-dimensional Hermitian square matrix

Tags: matrices, mathematical-physics, diagonalization, quantum-mechanics, hermitian-matrices

I have a quantum state which takes the following form:

$$\rho = \sum_{b, \,c \, = \,0}^\infty \frac{(-igt)^b(igt)^c}{\sqrt{b!c!}}\vert b\rangle\langle c\vert.$$

This is an ***infinite*** Hermitian matrix since $\rho = \overline\rho ^{\mathsf T}$, which can be written in the form:

$$\rho = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & -igt & \frac{-g^2t^2}{\sqrt{2!}} & \frac{ig^3t^3}{\sqrt{3!}} & \cdots \\
  igt & g^2t^2 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
  \frac{-g^2t^2}{\sqrt{2!}} & \vdots & \frac{g^4t^4}{\sqrt{4}} & \ldots & \ldots \\
  \frac{-ig^3t^3}{\sqrt{3!}} & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ldots\\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots\\
 & & & & & \frac{(gt)^{2n}}{n!} 
 \end{pmatrix}$$

where the element in the corner corresponds to coefficient in the $b=n$, $c=n$ term. I need to diagonalise this matrix so that there are elements only on the diagonal. There are some factors that can influence the choice to achieve this:

1. The matrix $\rho$ is Hermitian
2. The diagonal terms are suppressed (and are thus the smallest) due to the $n!$ term on the denominator.

How can I achieve a diagonalised matrix and what would be the result in this case?

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175149/2451

Answer (score 4):

Set
$$|v\rangle := \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-igt)^k}{\sqrt{k!}}|k\rangle,$$
Then your density matrix is simply given by
$$\rho = |v\rangle\langle v|.$$
Hence it is a rank-1 projection, i.e. $\rho$ describes a pure state. The norm of $|v\rangle$ is $e^{\frac12g^2t^2}$, so that if you take $e^{-\frac12g^2t^2}|v\rangle$ and complete it to an orthonormal basis of your Hilbert space, you have the matrix representation
$$\rho = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&\cdots\\0&0&\cdots\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\end{bmatrix}.$$
**Remark** Observe that the trace of $\rho$ is precisely $e^{g^2t^2}$ which must be 1 if $\rho$ has to represent a density matrix.

Comment: The norm of $\vert\upsilon\rangle$ is that which is written as $\rho$ in the original question, which reduces to $e^{\frac{1}{2}g^2t^2}$ if and only if $b=c$.

Comment: Yes. That's because the norm square of that vector coincides with the trace of $\rho$